# Ldap connection in .net C#

Tags: c#, email, ldap

I have an application where I can send emails. Now am asked to use `ldap`  to authenticate the user email. Am very new to this concept. I have been given a `ldap` server link. No idea how to proceed with that. Any article or hits will be greatly helpful.

Here is the code am trying with

```
public static UserDetail GetUserDetails(string EmailId, string domainName)
{
    UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();

    try
    {
        string filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass={0})(sAMAccountName={1}))", "person", EmailId);
        string[] properties = new string[] { "fullname" };

        DirectoryEntry adRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domainName, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(adRoot);
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(properties);
        searcher.Filter = filter;
        SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
        string displayName = directoryEntry.Properties["displayName"[0].ToStrin();
        string firstName = directoryEntry.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString();
        string lastName = directoryEntry.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
        string emailId = directoryEntry.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();

        userDetail.EmailId = emailId;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    return userDetail;
}
```

I want to achieve it on click of search button. How do I call the method and pass variables.

Comment: An application where you can send emails, and the adresses must be "authenticated"? Who is sending the email - a logged in user, or anyone? Is this an open-to-the-public application, or an internal intranet/business application?

Comment: it is internal.a loggedin user sends the email.and his email id has to be checked wid ldap entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// and with the e-mail of "bruce@example.com"
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.EmailAddress = "bruce@example.com";

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// try to find that user
UserPrincipal found = srch.FindOne() as UserPrincipal;

if(found != null)
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is the user that matched the e-mail given
}
else
{
    // there wasn't any user with that e-mail address in your AD
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: getting an error as no definition for email.And where to specify the domain name?

Comment: @user1665707: a quick check [of the wonderful MSDN documentation on `UserPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.aspx) shows that the property is called `EmailAddress` - change that and you're fine.

Comment: If the email address testbox is empty i need to add a validation or display a reeor message.I tried it with if else but am getting an error in this line UserPrincipal found = srch.FindOne() as UserPrincipal; .By using javascript also i get the same error. Any suggestions

Comment: @user1665707: that's a **whole new question** - don't keep asking more and more in comments - if you have a new question - **post** a new quesiton!

Answer (score 1):

Given the input of emailAddress (type string) this code will search the LDAP directory for a user with a matching email address and return some information on the user:

```
string fullName = string.Empty;
            string givenName = string.Empty;
            string distinguishedName = string.Empty;
            string sAMAccountName = string.Empty;
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN"))
            {
                using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
                {
                    foreach (Principal result in searcher.FindAll())
                    {
                        var de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

                        if (de.Properties["cn"].Value.ToString().Contains(" "))
                        {

                            //var userEntry = new DirectoryUser(de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString());
                            var currentUserEmail = de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString().ToLower();
                            if (currentUserEmail == emailAddress)
                            {

                                if (de.Properties["cn"].Value != null)
                                    fullName = de.Properties["cn"].Value.ToString();
                                if (de.Properties["givenName"].Value != null)
                                   givenName = de.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();
                                if (de.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value != null)
                                    distinguishedName =de.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
                                if (de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value != null)
                                    sAMAccountName = de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString();


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

It requires a reference to :

```
System.DirectoryServices;
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

One caveat I would like to mention is, directory look up routines can be quite slow. If you have 100,000 users on your domain, this process will take a while to run. WHat I tend to do, is dump the output of a directory search to a database table on a regular basis, and perform any lookups on that table. The frequency of the database dumps will of course depend on your business logic. Sometimes I simply truncate the table before performing a new dump, and in other circumstances, I dump to a 'staging' table, and only apply 'delta' updates to the active directoy record table.

Comment: Am getting an error ..object not set to instance of an object    Line 103:                            {                            
Line 104:                                //var userEntry = new DirectoryUser(de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString());  
Line 105:                                var currentUserEmail = de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString().ToLower();
Line 106:                                if (currentUserEmail == "mayur.shinde@telnet.com")

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Error...

Comment: even after the search is complete the loop for findall goes on and then i get an error.please help.

Comment: Add a exit condition to the loop when the record you are searching for has been found.

Comment: marc_s's solution is a lot more graceful

Comment: If the email address testbox is empty i need to add a validation or display a error message.I tried it with if else but am getting an error in this line UserPrincipal found = srch.FindOne() as UserPrincipal; .By using javascript also i get the same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

- Connect to the directory server, using SSL if possible. Promoting a non-secure connection to a secure connection with the StartTLS extended operation is also possible.
- Transmit a SEARCH request to the server that contains the base DN from which the client wishes the search to begin, the scope of the search (base, one-level, or sub-tree), a filter using the information the LDAP client knows that will narrow the search results to the desired user, and the attribute `1.1`.
- The server will respond with the a SEARCH response containing the number of entries that matched the search request parameters and the distinguished names of each entry that matched.
- Transmit a BIND request to the directory server over the secure connection. The BIND request contains a distinguished name and the credentials for the distinguished name
- The directory server will verify the credentials and return a BIND response with an integer result code indicating whether the credentials matched those stored in the server database

#### see also

- [LDAP: programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)
- [LDAP: search practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)